vscode doesn't detect g++ / Can't use **Run C/C++ File** in vscode
I'm using NixOS tought I doubt that's the problem in this particular instance.
I have both gcc and g++ installed as per gcc --version and g++ --version giving the output(s):
Copyright (C) 2023 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

and
Copyright (C) 2023 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

As you can see by this picture after having pressed the Run C/C++ File (both run and debug look the same) no options appear.

It also doesn't seem to be a path error of some sort as I can execute something like g++ main.cpp -o main just fine inside the vscode terminal and the output file also runs just fine.
To further push that there is no error in the path, when I press Configure Default Build Task.. both g++ and gcc show up with the correct paths.
Sorry for any broken English as it's not my first language.
